# Putting database production password on json config file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Is it a bad practice to store my database password on json config file?

Like:

production.json

```
{
  "database": {
     "user": "...",
     "pass": "...
  }
}
```

?

If so, how to avoid that? I see a lot of people doing that, isn't this really danger?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be bad if you upload your config production.json / production.js with your credentials or secrets to a public repository like GitHub, Bitbucket, etc. The wrong people could have access to write to your database, ability to unhash your passwords, etc.

There are a couple of ways to circumvent this:

1. Add your production.json / production.js to your .gitignore file so when you push changes to a respository, it doesn't push your credentials up
2. Leave an example template production.json / production.js file filling the user, password, and secret fields with a holder like DATABASE_USER, DATABASE_PASSWORD, APP_SECRET (more common)

For another user to use your code, they would either (respectively) :

1. Have to message you to get the right config production.json / production.js file
2. Create their own production.json / production.js file, based on the template you supplied filling in their own database user, password and app secret (more common)

Hope that clears things up.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter if the password is in the clear or not. If someone can look at the configuration he/she can probably look at the program too and figure out how to connect to the db anyways. Just make sure the configuration is only readable by the programs that really need it.